# Redirect URLs from root domain to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm not good at .htaccess. I wanted to restrict all the traffic to my mail website and need to direct to sub.domain.com using .htaccess also the parameter after the main URL should be maintained during redirection using `.htaccess`.

This is how my existing .htaccess looks like,

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to public folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.in$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.in$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1.example.in$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain2.example.in$ [NC,OR]

#For DEV system
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.loc$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.loc$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1.example.loc$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain2.example.loc$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/
RewriteRule (.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 [L]
```

I tried using,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.example.in/$1 [R=301,L]
```

at the end of above `.htaccess`. But it is not working. Please help.